# Arch ufw enabling

Tags: arch-linux, ufw

To enable UFW in Debian I do:

```
ufw --force enable
```

I understand from the Arch documentation that do so in Arch I should do instead:

```
systemctl start ufw
systemctl enable ufw
```

By "enabling" I mean "Ensuring UFW will run after each system boot".

Is my way of doing so in Arch totally resembles the way to do so in Debian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply `ufw enable` - after enabling the service.

Comment: in `ufw enable` I assume you meant `systemctl enable ufw`. I accepted your answer though it'll be good if you'll edit to clarify I believe. I really think it'll raise the chance for upvotes ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

`ufw --force enable` Does the same thing in Arch and Debian based systems (inclusive of spin-off distros like Ubuntu, Mint, Manjaro, etc).

`systemctl start ufw` -> tells the ufw daemon to start now.
`systemctl enable ufw` -> enables the ufw daemon to start on future boots.

The `systemctl` commands are part of system D, which is the init system for BOTH Debian and Arch. Using `systemctl list-units` on either distro will allow you to see the all the daemons that are running/failed.

To confirm if your firewall is active, you can run `sudo ufw status`.

Comment: technically: 1) it's not a daemon, because there's no ufw process that stays running . "service" is fine. 2) It's "systemd". See "Spelling" here: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/.